# Derivation of a Bayesian predictive probability

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose a random variable $Y$ is governed by an unknown parameter $p$. From a set of observations $X$, I want to draw the probability of $Y=y$. How can I compute the Bayesian predictive probability $f(Y=y|X)?$

In a reference paper(http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~edgeorge/Research_papers/Bcollab.pdf) equation (6), I saw the derivation should be $$f(Y=y|X)=\int_pf(Y=y|p)f(X|p)\pi(p)dp.$$

How could I derive this using Bayes rule?

Comment: That $f(Y=y|X) =$ in the equation should be $f(Y=y|X) \propto$...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606372/how-to-derive-the-posterior-predictive-distribution

Comment: See the second answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606372/how-to-derive-the-posterior-predictive-distribution

Comment: Thank you @DaveHarris. I'll refer to the posting.